# ArrayAdapter without refering to xml

Tags: android, xml, android-arrayadapter

I am working on List View with section headers, now i have a ArrayAdapter like this:

```
header = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.header);
```

and i am using header in this way:

```
view = header.getView(sectionnum, convertView, parent);
        if (view != null) {
            TextView headerTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.header_title);
}
```

Now i dont want to use the `R.layout.header` xml, instead i have a programatically created layout which i need to use, how to use that instead of xml?

Answer (score 1):

just extend ArrayAdapter and override its getView method

Comment: can you please help me with an example?

Answer (score 1):

```
header = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.header) {

  @Override
  public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          if (converView == null) {
                // inflate convertView;
          }

          // fill up covertView

         return convertView;
  }
}
```

Comment: But still we are refering to the R.layout.header here , i dont want any reference to that , can you please help me on that?

Comment: in getView() you can inflate R.layout.whatever

Comment: yes correct but here as he has shown header = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.header) { he is refering to layout xml

Comment: aa, ok, if you dont want to inflate any xml layout but rather created your layout via api calls just return it in getView

Comment: @pskink thanks but can you please show me a example if you dont mind, because i already have this header = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.header); and i am not getting how to do it without using the xml

Comment: instead of header = new
ArrayAdapter<String>
(context, R.layout.header); do header = new
MyArrayAdapter<String>
(context, 0); where MyArrayAdapter is a class that extends ArrayAdapter and overrides getView method which returns your view that you created using some api calls e.g new TextView()

Answer (score 1):

This is the area to answers, but I could figure out how to post it as a comment to those others comments up here.

So, I'm getting this same problem. I think that is because if this ID's that I don't have because I'm trying to use all dynamically.

I already tried call my constructor putting (context, 0, list-of-Objects)

Any other solution to try?

```
06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xc
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:230)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3640)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at com.example.frame.graphics.ContextArrayAdapter.getView(ContextArrayAdapter.java:68)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2143)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:645)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:425)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:645)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:425)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1052)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    06-13 15:48:18.273: E/AndroidRuntime(14326):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Edit 1: So, this is my code:**

```
package com.example.frame.graphics;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ContextArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<contextitem> {

    Activity            context;
    // int layoutResourceId;
    List<contextitem>   objects;

    public ContextArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<contextitem> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = (Activity) context;
        // this.layoutResourceId = textViewResourceId;
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        RelativeLayout row = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
        ContextHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            holder = new ContextHolder();
            holder.name = new TextView(context);
            holder.counter = new TextView(context);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsName = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            paramsName.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsCount = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            paramsName.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

            row = new RelativeLayout(context);
            row.addView(holder.name, paramsName);
            row.addView(holder.counter, paramsCount);
            row.setTag(holder);

            parent.addView(row, position);
        } else {
            holder = (ContextHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        contextitem contextItem = objects.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(contextItem.getName());
        int count = contextItem.getCount();
        if (count > -1) {
            holder.counter.setText(contextItem.getCount());
        } else {
            holder.counter.setText("");
        }

        return row;
    }

    static class ContextHolder {
        TextView    name;
        TextView    counter;
    }

}
```

**Edit 2: Solution (Finally)**
The thing is that we need that linear layout there. whether using XML or not.

```
package com.example.frame.graphics;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

import org.apache.cordova.api.LOG;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.frame.MainActivity;

public class ContextArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<contextitem> {

    Activity                    context;
    ArrayList<contextitem>      list;
    static private final String TAG = "ContextArrayAdapter.java";

    public ContextArrayAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.list_content);
        this.context = (Activity) context;
        this.list = new ArrayList<contextitem>();
    }

    @Override
    public void add(contextitem object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // super.add(object);
        if (MainActivity.debug) {
            LOG.d(TAG, "add Called");
        }
        list.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void addAll(Collection<? extends contextitem> collection) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // super.addAll(collection);
        // super.add(object);
        if (MainActivity.debug) {
            LOG.d(TAG, "addAll Called");
        }
        list.addAll(collection);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(contextitem object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // super.remove(object);
        if (MainActivity.debug) {
            LOG.d(TAG, "remove Called");
        }
        list.remove(object);
    }

    public ArrayList<contextitem> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // return super.getCount();
        if (MainActivity.debug) {
            LOG.d(TAG, "getCount Called");
        }
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public contextitem getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // return super.getItem(position);
        if (MainActivity.debug) {
            LOG.d(TAG, "getItem Called");
        }
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getPosition(contextitem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // return super.getPosition(item);
        if (MainActivity.debug) {
            LOG.d(TAG, "getPosition Called");
        }
        return list.indexOf(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void sort(Comparator<? super contextitem> comparator) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // super.sort(comparator);
        if (MainActivity.debug) {
            LOG.d(TAG, "sort Called");
        }
        Collections.sort(list, comparator);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (MainActivity.debug) {
            LOG.d(TAG, "getView Called");
        }
        LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout) convertView;
        ContextHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            holder = new ContextHolder();
            holder.name = new TextView(context);
            holder.counter = new TextView(context);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsName = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            paramsName.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsCount = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            paramsCount.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

            RelativeLayout innerLayout = new RelativeLayout(context);
            innerLayout.addView(holder.name, paramsName);
            innerLayout.addView(holder.counter, paramsCount);

            row = new LinearLayout(context);
            row.addView(innerLayout);
            row.setTag(holder);

            // LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
            // context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            // row = (LinearLayout)
            // inflater.inflate(com.example.frame.R.layout.context_row, parent,
            // false);
            // holder = new ContextHolder();
            // holder.name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.context_row_name);
            // holder.counter = (TextView)
            // row.findViewById(R.id.context_row_count);
            // row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ContextHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        contextitem contextItem = this.getItem(position);
        holder.name.setText(contextItem.getName());
        int count = contextItem.getCount();
        if (count > -1) {
            holder.counter.setText(Integer.toString(contextItem.getCount()));
        } else {
            holder.counter.setText("");
        }

        return row;
    }

    class ContextHolder {
        TextView    name;
        TextView    counter;
    }

}
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17050008/cannot-get-headers-working-with-separatedlistadapter

Comment: I edit my "answer" question and put my code. So, should I set and ID to my view (RelativeLayout) ??
Where does that HEAD_ID come from? Should I have a head in my listview??